# How to select value inside an object

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to store 1 or more values that are inside an array into a scope. This is the result of my JSONP service,

```
angular.callbacks._7({
  "id":157336,"results":[
    {"id":"53db3c790e0a26189a000d09","iso_639_1":"en","key":"ePbKGoIGAXY","name":"Trailer 3","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"550df44b9251413554004d43","iso_639_1":"en","key":"KlyknsTJk0w","name":"Own it today","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"533ec6fcc3a3685448009ccc","iso_639_1":"en","key":"nyc6RJEEe0U","name":"Teaser","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"5376ab510e0a26141c0005a8","iso_639_1":"en","key":"zSWdZVtXT7E","name":"Trailer","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
    {"id":"545da247c3a3685362005187","iso_639_1":"en","key":"Lm8p5rlrSkY","name":"Trailer 2","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"}
  ]
})
```

And I'm trying to store all the `key` values inside a scope called `$scope.youtubeTrailer`

But if I do it like this,

```
$scope.youtubeTrailer = response; 
console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)
```

The scope consists of an object (the movie) and inside that object is an array with the 5 id's. So what would be the correct selector for something like this?

If I search like this,

```
 console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer.key)
```

I get an 'undefined´

*** EDIT ***

I've tried to solution below,

```
movieAdd.trailer(movie.id)
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.youtubeTrailer =[];
    console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)

    angular.forEach(response.results, function(item){
      console.log ('Hello world')
      if (item.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
        $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
      }
    });
```

The `console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)` shows that the scope is empty. And the `forEach` function doesnt fire because the `Hello log` doesn't get shown in the console. If I change `$scope.youtubeTrailer =[];` into `$scope.youtubeTrailer = response;` I do have the object in the scope but still the `forEach` doesn't fire.

*** EDIT 2 ***

By changinge `response.results` into `response` the `forEach` does fire.

*** EDIT 3 ***

I've got it somewhat working. I was getting the array in the scope, but when I saved the scope value in the create function it showed as null in the database. That's because I was trying to save an array. Using javascripts `join` I converted the array to a string which can be saved.

```
movieAdd.trailer(movie.id)
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.youtubeTrailer = [];
    angular.forEach(response, function(item){
      if (item.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
        $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
        var youtubeArray = $scope.youtubeTrailer
        var youtubeString = youtubeArray.join();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below basically is looping through the `response.results` array, which contains 5 objects. Each oject is assigned to the variable `item`. Check `item` has property of `key`, if true, add the value of `item.key` to `$scope.youtubeTrailer`.

```
$scope.youtubeTrailer =[];
angular.forEach(response.results, function(item) {
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
    $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
  }
});
```

Here is the link for [Angular ForEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've tried to work the code in my controller but it looks like that `forEach` function doesn't fire. I´ve updated my question to show the problem.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `moiveAdd.trailer`? I am wondering that maybe the `service` cause the problem. Can you `console.log(response)` before the `forEach` function and post the log?

Comment: Not sure what the problem was before. But I did fix it all, as you can see in the edits made in the question.

Comment: Ok, that's good then. Another thing is, since you are using `.then()` function, it is a good practice that you implement error handling. It will be easy for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.youtubeTrailer` isn't just an object, it contains an *array* and its inside that array that the `key` field is.  So, you're going to need to access the five interior items with an array access.  e.g. `$scope.youtubeTrailer.results[0].key`

Comment: Where would I use that code? Because I get an `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error if I place it after the `.then` call.